# MongoDb callback returns value undefined whereas Mongo shell returns the right results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs, mongo-shell

I've a mongodb collection which has more than 20 million collection.

```
db.collection.find({ 'attr.type': new RegExp('automotive snow' 'i') }).limit(10);
```

Above mongo shell query returns the results as expected, But implementing the same in a node.js application it doesn't seem to work right. I can't really figure out the reason.

Sample node.js code

```
db.collection.find({ 'attr.type': new RegExp('automotive snow' 'i') }, function(err, docs) {
 console.log(docs); // returns undefined
});
```

I use `mongojs` module, Tried native `mongodb` module as well but the results seemed to be the same hence decided to use `mongojs` module.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: If `docs` is `undefined`, `err` should hold an error. What does it say?

Comment: Thank you. That helped me understand a bit more about the problem. It shows `connection 1 to server.ip timed out`.

Comment: Fixed by setting SocketTimeOut options on mongo connection.

Comment: what happen if you use `db.collection("collectionName").find` ?

Comment: @ShaishabRoy I was using a different module `mongojs` like i mentioned in the question. Right now i switched to `mongodb` and set a socket timeout to solve the issue.